# Python and pandas loop failed to write row in xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, for-loop

i have one probleme with my script(here at start you have a partial script),i charge my file Xlsx and i let selenium find information who i need in some page and he add result in column when this finished. but my excel file have the last result duplicate on all rows. and naturaly i want one result by row. can you see what i've forget?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
import os
import unittest
import csv
import re
import easygui
os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'

#choix du fichier Excel
chemin = easygui.fileopenbox(msg=None, title='Selectionner votre fichier Excel', default='*.xlsx', filetypes='', multiple=False)
#Connexion au site
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
print("connexion au site")
print("démarage du process")
data = pd.read_excel(chemin)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['info'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
for num in df.info:    
        print(num)
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "search")))
        finally:
                #fin
            x = True
        elem = driver.find_element_by_id("search")
        elem.send_keys(str(num))
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
                # récupération des données
        driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('waiting-indicator').style.display = 'none';")
                #verification de la presence du premier element
        val = 30 # in seconds
        driver.implicitly_wait(val)
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/p")))
        finally:
                #fin
            x = True
        print("récupération des datas")
        info1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/p').text
        info2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/p').text
        info3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/p').text
        info4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/p').text
        info5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/p').text
        print("ajout des datas au fichier")
        df1 = df1.assign(type = info1, type2 = info2, type3 = info3, type4 = info4, type5 = info5)
        
        print("next")
print("opération terminé")
df1.to_excel(chemin+"out.xlsx", index = False, header=True)
driver.close()
```

Comment: you need to store the data in your loop and then write to excel after the loop. In current code, you are writing one row at a time and then the next row is overwriting the previous one.

Answer (score -1):

Well I finally found, with ur logic help "simpleApp".
here i have add this before the loop:

`lst = []`

`cols = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3','type4', 'type5']`

in my loop in the place of line with assign i've add this:

`resultat = lst.append([info1, info2, info3, info4, info5])`

And at the end after my loop i've add this :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=cols)
final = concat([data,df1], axis=1)
print(final)
final.to_excel(chemin+"out.xlsx", index = False, header=True)
driver.close()
print("opération terminé")
```